# Populating JTable with user input

Tags: java, swing, jtable

so I've been having such a problem as for how to populate JTable with user input, i got table created but it just dosn't get the data from an object.

```
SportClub club = new SportClub();
            String name = club.getName();
            int points = club.getPoints();
            int wins = club.getWins();
            int defeats = club.getDefeats();
            int draws = club.getDraws();
            int goalsFor = club.getGoalsScored();
            int goalsAgainst = club.getGoalsReceived();
            int difference = goalsFor - goalsAgainst;

            Object data[][] = {
                    {name, wins, draws, defeats, goalsFor, goalsAgainst,difference, points}
            };
            String column[] = {"Club Name", "Wins", "Draws", "Loses", "GF", "GA", "Goal Difference", "Total Points"};

           
            JTable prTable = new JTable(data, column);
            JFrame frame = new JFrame("Premier League Table");
            JScrollPane scroll = new JScrollPane(prTable);
            prTable.setFillsViewportHeight(true);
            frame.add(scroll);
            frame.pack();
            frame.setVisible(true);
            frame.setDefaultCloseOperation(JFrame.EXIT_ON_CLOSE);
```

Feel like I should have used the for loop but just have a trouble where to place it.

Comment: Not sure how you expect to see any data. You create an empty "SportClub" object. *Feel like I should have used the for loop* - if you expect to see multiple sport clubs then yes you will need a loop. I suggest you start by create a DefaultTableModel with just the column names and 0 rows. Then you can use the `addRow(   )` method of the DefaultTableModel to add rows of information. Then you create the JTable using the model.

Comment: I have a separate method addTeam() and addGame() which basically asks user for an input as for teams names and game statistics and store the data in an object. But thanks for a hint